# Is there any function to detect site domain changed?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I want to show an `alert` box if my ***javascript code*** is copied to another site.

Is there any function to detect domain is change and keep alert msg box appear if original domain is not detected?

Comment: In the way you want to achieve this, it's not possible at all. Any function that checks the current domain would just be deleted by the person who steals the code anyway. The best you can do is properly licence the code and take legal action if that code is stolen.

Comment: Wow really @JoshBrolin. Since in order to copy your javascript code and put it somewhere else, they have the source code. So how hard would it be for someone to change it? I understand you're still barely a beginner but did you even think about it before you got all snarky with the person who made the first comment?

Comment: @JoshBrolin: @nbokmans has perfectly served an answer to your question. Didn`t he? You asked "is it possible". Then please update your question.

Comment: check https://obfuscator.io/

Comment: Someone copies your code. They get an `alert` when they run it. They *Ctrl + F* the message in the code and delete it.

Comment: you can try "document.referrer" it will work

Comment: i just want that function for my practicing and that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope it will help

```
  <script>

     var ref = document.referrer
     if(ref !== "https://yourdomain.com"){
           alert(ref);
      }

    // or you can do this

     var host = window.location.hostname
     if(host !== "yourdomain.com"){
           alert(host);
      }

  </script>
```

Comment: should be "unequal" not equal: if(ref !== "https://yourdomain.com/")

Comment: on which domain you are trying @johh Brolin

Comment: now they alert on my original domain and their inner pages too

Comment: This will console the previous url if i go to inner page i just need the domain detection yourwebsite.com

$(document).ready(function () {
   var ref = document.referrer
    console.log(ref)    });

Comment: then use "window.location.hostname"